# Can I add new colors to SUI.COLORS for my custom theme?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

My team is planning to build a custom theme for semantic-ui and use it with semantic-ui-react, but we want a custom color pallet with different names. Is that possible? I am thinking somehow I can append the colors to SUI.COLOR?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those colors are only for simple PropType checking of OOTB colors in Semantic UI's core CSS. If you are going to compile your own CSS you can use one of the existing colors and change the hex value when you compile your theme. So if the global "red" is not the one you want to use, change the hex color when you compile your CSS. Then you can use "red" as a value for the `color` prop on SUIR components.

The other way if you want to keep the OOTB colors as-is and add a new color like "brick", you would have to add tooling to support that new color class when you compile your CSS. Then you could set that color as a `className` prop instead of a `color` prop.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer - can I ask for clarification please because I really want to do option 2 (keep OOTB colors as is). I see the Semantic-UI-React code type checking the colors specified for the controls and I'm not sure how adding it as a className prop would work? I'm not even sure I understand what you mean by a className prop or tooling. Could you please provide a small sample or help me understand what you mean. Thank you very much.

Comment: The way styles work in Semantic UI React is by rendering markup with the class names that Semantic UI requires. `<Button color='red' />` will render `<button class='ui button red' />` in the DOM. There are no hex colors inlined. Notice in that example that the `color` prop was used. However, you can render the exact same markup using the `className` prop: `<Button className='red' />`

The only way to change the hex color in the CSS is to compile those styles using the build tools in SUI core, or write your own overriding CSS.